# How to use actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) with more that one button?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

So my assignment says to create a sequential file. My professor gave me this simple code for the actionperformed:

```
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )  { 

    //FOR STATE AND COUNTRY
    String country = (String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = states.get( country );

        if (o == null)
        {
            comboBox_2.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox_2.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
        }
        //****DONE WITH THE STATE AND COUNTRY COMBOBOXEZ*****

    addRecord( ) ;



    if ( e.getSource( ) == btnDone )  {
      try {
        output.close( ); 
      }
      catch ( IOException io )  {
        System.err.println( "File not closed properly\n" +
           e.toString( ) );
        System.exit(1);
      }



      System.exit(0); 


    }
  }
```

}
it basically says if you hit anything but the "Done" button, it creates a sequential file. What should i do to choose what each action will do? i did a jcombobox with countries and states, and when i choose a country, it creates the file and then it gets me to the country's states.Hope you can help me out thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the handler to more than one button? What makes you thinking that you cannot do that?

Comment: i dont know how, or at least i think i dont know.. i tried a lot of stuff different buttons and if statements, i suck!!

Comment: You might want to tell your professor that doing I/O on the swing UI thread is a bad idea.

Comment: to be fair this was originally for awt components, don;t know if the same applies there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your problem, but...

You can use:

- [`ActionEvent#getSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource--) to get the source component of the event.  Assuming that you can reference the other components, you can simply use this to compare them, for example `if (e.getSource( ) == btnDone)  {`
- [`ActionEvent#getActionCommand`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand--) which returns the `actionCommand` associated with the component (set via the `setActionCommand` on supporting components), which provides you means of determining the type of event, without needing a reference to the source components, this is also useful when you might have a "common" action that can triggered in multiple different ways.

Now, generally speaking, when `actionPerformed` is called, you want to determine what triggered the action and take appropriate action, so the case of your code, you might do something more like...

```
if (e.getSource() == comboBox_1) {
    String country = (String) comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();
    Object o = states.get(country);

    if (o == null) {
        comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
    } else {
        comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
    }
    //****DONE WITH THE STATE AND COUNTRY COMBOBOXEZ*****

    addRecord();
} else if (e.getSource() == btnDone) {
    try {
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.err.println("File not closed properly\n"
                + e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.exit(0);

}
```

This is a rather "old" way to approach designing `ActionListener`, which harks back to the days before [inner/anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), where is was just simpler to create a single `ActionListener` class.

Now days it's generally more preferable to use inner/anonymous classes to generate small, isolated and contextual listeners, which might look something like...

```
comboBox_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String country = (String) comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = states.get(country);

        if (o == null) {
            comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
        } else {
            comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
        }
        //****DONE WITH THE STATE AND COUNTRY COMBOBOXEZ*****

        addRecord();
    }
});
```

This is a self contained, contextual unit work, designed for a single use of work.  Generally it's easier to read and maintain as the context is well defined and you're not trying to tip-toe around a bunch of unrelated work.

If you need something that's more re-usable, then you should have a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: thanks man, i wish i knew this before i started my assignment it would be less of a mess, and i probably wouldn't be stuck.  Still though it happens the same i can't figure this shit out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was right in front of my eyes, here it is for future users.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 

  //FOR STATE AND COUNTRY
  String country = (String)comboBox_1.getSelectedItem();
  Object o = states.get(country);
  if (o == null){
      comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
  }
  else{
      comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[])o));
  }
  //****DONE WITH THE STATE AND COUNTRY COMBOBOXES*****

  // this was the solution for my problem
  if(e.getSource==buttonToAddRecords){
      addRecord( ) ;
  }

  if(e.getSource( ) == btnDone){
    try{
      output.close( ); 
    }
    catch(IOException io){
      System.err.println("File not closed properly\n" +
         e.toString( ));
      System.exit(1);
    }
    System.exit(0); 
  }
}
```